# Flex 4 How to enable Mouse events on all overlapping objects

Tags: events, flex4, mouse, overlap

I`m stuck in this situation where I have a transparent container overlapping other objects.I plan to use this overlapping Transparent Object to show moving objects since it implements absolute positioning. The problem is I want the mouse to work on the overlapping container as well as the ones below it. So far what I have found is that you disable the overlapping objects mouse events and let the events pass through. But what if I want all overlapping objects to catch the mouse. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Just change 'bubbles' property to true.